# App runs in VS iis express but not in IIS 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, iis-express, iis-8

I am having an interesting issue with IIS 8. I can run the app just find. However after triggering a sql query I get the dreaded "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'".

The real kicker to all of this is that when I run in IIS Express with Visual Studio 2013 it works fine.

[IIS Authentication Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7E7g.png)

Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Any/All help is appreciated!

Comment: Lex, 

I read your blog post thank you for the information. However I have changed the appPool identity to all possible choices local service, local system, network service and application pool identity don't work. However when I set the pool identity to my account under custom account it works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: There are domain users that have logins on the sql server I want to have them use their domain credentials when the page loads, the app would then use these credentials to connect to the sql server.

Comment: impersonation is only the first step. If you don't have Kerberos delegation configured properly (an AD setting), then still the error can happen.

Comment: This app used to be an ASP.net app and it worked fine. I re-factored it as an MVC web app and now it doesn't work. I'm not sure that kerberos delegation makes sense in this case.

Comment: if you check how complicated Kerberos delegation is, you will see why it can easily be broken and fail to work. Besides, "it worked fine" is an invalid claim, as have you carefully checked how it was configured thoroughly?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the account that is running the app pool in IIS has access to SQL server. If that doesn't work then try changing the account that the app pool is running under to like NetworkService or LocalService and see if that has any effect.

Also try changing some of the other app pool settings in the "Advanced Settings..." dialog such as the managed pipeline mode and enable 32-bit applications.

Comment: So far I have only been able to get the page to load properly when I change the app pool identity to a custom account and turn off asp.net impersonation.

However I want to use the credentials that the user types in when the page loads. I wanted to also add this web app is an intranet app only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help.

What ended up happening is that we just used a local sql account.

We are going to use AD to control who has access to the page.

Using the `<deny roles="DOMAIN\Domain Users"/>`

option in web config file.